# node.js setInterval vs real time

Tags: javascript, time

I am working on a tool that require to measure certain amount of time (for example 2 minutes) since user interaction with a tool, this time also needs to be displayed for the user.

I started simple server loop for this reason:

```
setInterval(function() {
    measure.time();
}, 10);
```

i created a code for to calculate:

```
this.reset = 0;
this.step = 100 // 10 ms server loop, adds 1 to reset === 100 is 1 second
this.time = function() {
    if(this.reset === this.step) {
        console.log('SPAWN', new Date());
        this.reset = 0;
    }
    this.reset++;
};
```

this is the result of my approach:

[image]

The idea is to show clock for the user and update it every second, but it skips seconds rather often, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Timers are never precise. Thats not how it works. However, the more timers you shedule, the more error you get. So may simply do a 1s loop...

Comment: What about MomentJS ?